# Close modal dialog and redirect to previous page with parameter

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, modal-dialog

I have opened up a page in a modal dialog by using

```
OpenPopUpPage('myPage.aspx')
```

The page contains a button. Clicking on the button should cause the modal dialog to close, perform some server side action and redirect to the previous page with some parameter added (this is because I want to display a label revealing if the server side action was successful).  I know that I can close the modal dialog from code behind using

```
System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup();</script>");
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.End();
```

but don´t know how to combine it with redirect functionality. I also observed that parameters are not added to the url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be accomplished with

```
context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.navigateParent('myParentPage.aspx');</script>");
```